# Reloading form without losing the variables values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I click on a button my form needs to reload, without loosing some variables.

For example:

A game needs to be reset, but the high score variable needs to be kept to count with the next one.
`"Application.Reset();"` does reset the `form1`, but also all the variables.
Is there a way out without using databases, because we haven't learned that yet.

Comment: You can write to a file and read from that.

Answer (score 1):

**It can be achieved by**

> 1.saving the data in Database
>
> 2.XML file (Write and Read)
>
> 3.Setting the properties of Class
>
> 4.Using the Static Variables**

Comment: If you're not actually restarting the application, static variables are probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: Ya correct and also its possible by Class Object also if object is a parameter to form from parent form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Class and have properties and methods in that and pass it to the form. Upon exit of the form, update your Class values with those that were changed on the form.

After that you will need to figure out "storing" the class in some sort of Stream and being able to reload your class from that stream. (XML, Binary, Protobuf, JSON) there are many ways.

Comment: Sounds great, I'll try that immediately !

Comment: Worked like a charm ! This because I have 2 Forms running, and wile reloading the other form, I kept the value saved in the second form for a while... sounds weird but it worked !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Settings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx

and save your data on reset/closing